# Error while Starting Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot-issues, cpu, failure

**Enviroment:**

Device: Rasberry Pi 2

OS: Raspbian

Last sign of life: 8.March 2021

**Problem**

Since 8th of march I've got no message of my raspberry pi, so I get them and try to boot with a connected monitor.

On the picture you can see the error message. The pi stop to run here.
Is this possible to fix? if yes, how can I fix it? If no, how can I get my data of my PI user?

If I reboot the py, the last message is all the time an other one, but the message before the last is every time **SMP: failed to stop secondary CPUs**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a new SD card with a new version of the operating system?  I take it you have no backup if you are trying to get the data off the card so you need to get a computer that can read the EXT4 partition on the card and get the data off.  This could be your Pi with the old card put in a SD to USB adapter.